# Modifying an instance variable from inside a completion block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, block, instance-variables

I have written some code to modify a instance variable from inside a completionblock handler that is being part of the "reverseGeocodeLocation" Method. Here is the code first of all:

```
- (void)reverseGeocodeLocation:(CLLocation *)aLocation {
    CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    __block __strong NSArray *dataArray;

    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:aLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            CLLocation *userLocation = [placemark location];

            NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lat. %f degrees", userLocation.coordinate.latitude];
            NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Long. %f degrees", userLocation.coordinate.longitude];
            NSString *altitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Alt. %f m", userLocation.altitude];
            NSString *speed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Speed %f m/s", userLocation.speed];
            NSString *course = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Course %f degrees", userLocation.course];

            dataArray = @[latitude, longitude, altitude, speed, course];

        // The data array is perfectly populated!!

            NSLog(@"Just checking... %@", dataArray);

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.tableViewRows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:dataArray];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });

        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    }];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    [self reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation];
}
```

And here is the code for the tableView:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark TabeView

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableViewRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And the rest of the VC:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
            self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            self.locationManager.delegate = self; // location manager delegate
            self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000;
            [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }

        // Create the Rows Array for the TableView
        self.tableViewRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create the TableView
    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    table.dataSource = self;
    table.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:table];
}
```

Well... as you can see, I want to populate the instance variable "tableViewRows". The population of the temporary array "dataArray" is working perfectly fine! All the values are being shown. And the population of the instance variable inside the method is working fine as well! But only INSIDE the completion block.

As soon as I try to access the instance variable outside of the completion block, I receive an error message, that there are no values inside the array. Did I miss something important out?

I have already read that the "reverseGeocodeLocation" is an async message that couldn't be completed yet, when I try to read the instance var. But in my opinion that shouldn't be the case, because the completion block is already being called and I can log the entries of the arrays inside of the completion block.

I don't have a clue what to do now. I have the feeling, that it is a pretty easy solution and I totally don't get it for hours right now. Maybe you can give me a helping hand?

Thank you

Comment: What's the definition of 'tableViewRows'? Is it strong / retain? If not, it's getting released before you try to use it.

Comment: Hi! jep... it is @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tableViewRows;

Comment: Ensure that you switch back to the main thread before setting the data and calling the table view. Or at least make the property atomic and call the table on the main thread.

Comment: Exactly what exception are you getting and where? (show the code)

Comment: When I try to show the contents in the "cellforRowAtIndexPath":
cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableViewRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

I get the message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: I just edited the code in the question: I added the dispatch_sync to run the code on main thread when adding the array to the instance var. But still no effect

Comment: You don't really have to jump on main queue because geocoder calls you back on main queue. Are you sure that you're not reloading the table _before_ this block executes? Would be helpful to look at full VC code, maybe just the table handling part

Comment: I just have edited my code above to show you the tableview code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you're telling table view that you *always* have 5 rows in it, but it's probably not true. You should ask `self.tableViewRows.count` for an actual count. Given that, I think you're crashing on the first load of the table view, when it tries to reload itself, but tableViewRows is empty.

Plus, you should assign your tableView to property in viewDidLoad

Comment: I tried that as well.. but when I do that, the whole app is freezin'. And no table is shown at all. But more than that, the app is not responsive any more. The data seems to be all there. But only INSIDE the completion block. It does not manage to copy the code into the instance var and holding on to that.

Comment: I don't think it's unresponsive, change your table init line to `[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain]` so that your frame is correct, and table is plain so you can see scroll working

Comment: Just tried that.. you are correct in that part.. The app is responsive. But I just found out, that if I try to log the "dataArray" variable inside the reverseGeocodeLocation Method, and put a NSLOG after the closing brackets of the completion block, there is nothing in that array. Even though it is assigned as a __block variable. So the contents are only visible inside the completion block. That seems strange to me. The dataArray Variable should be filled with data by the completion block, shouldn't it? Thats why my instance var is empty as well!?

Comment: Well, no, when you log it outside the block it's empty because block hasn't fired yet, remember that it's body will be executed after you exit `reverseGeocodeLocation `

Comment: Hm... But this makes it even more strange to me... I can see the log output for the data-array inside the block. The block should be firing after that, shouldn't it? It is so bad to see that on so many levels :) I feel that I see the problem right in front of me, but I don't have a clue what to do

Comment: Inside the block your data is fine of course, I don't know what's the purpose of declaring dataArray outside the block to be honest, all you need is `self.tableViewRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[latitude...]]`

Comment: I just tried that. Very strange...... I changed the code like you said. But still an empty instance var outside the block. Inside everything is fine.

Comment: Oh yeah and I just don't see where you assign self.tableView in viewDidLoad, so it could be your table is just not reloading

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO! THAT WAS THE ANSWER!!!!! IT WAS JUST THE MISSING SELF.TABLEVIEW = TABLE

6h of excrutiating pain for this line of code!!!
You are fabulous!!!

Comment: Dmitry just found the missing link. My block code works perfectly fine. But for the last 6 hours I did not see, that I never assigned the table to self.tableView in viewdidLoad. Thank god, Dmitry noticed that so quickly! And thanks to you guys, as well!!